# Quest Spotlight oci.dll

Tags: oracle, dll, spotlight, quest

My Quest Spotlight Trial does not connect to DB. When I run the user wizard it always comes:

> ```
> Cannot load OCI DLL: oci.dll
> ```

It is a 64-bit Windows Server / 64 bit Oracle server.

I've already installed the 32 bit Oracle client and added the dict to path, but nothing worked.

Does someone have a tip for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Spotlight requirements](http://www.quest.com/spotlight-on-oracle/#requirements):

> Note: Spotlight will run on 64-bit versions of the client operating
>   system with the use of a 32-bit Oracle client.

If you have 64-bit server and 32-bit client installed on the same computer it's possible that Spotlight looks for `oci.dll` at wrong Oracle Home.

Examine order of Oracle home directories from Universal Installer and place 32-bit home first:

1. Run Oracle Universal Installer
2. Click "Installed Products" button
3. Switch to "Environment" tab
4. Reorder Oracle Homes with arrows on right side and click "Apply"

Comment: whould you mind helping me in this post too?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28061597/can-not-find-oci-dll-in-spolight

Answer (score 1):

InstallClient does not configure environment variables.
Solution:

- download instantclient_11_2(remember you InstallClient  path)
- PATH add :C:\ instantclient_11_2（OCI.DLL）
- New system environment variables:SQLPATH，LOCAL，TNS_ADMIN，LD_LIBRARY_PATH;content:C:\ instantclient_11_2

To use English, my English is bad

Answer (score 0):

if you use 64-bit pc, oracle doesn't compatible with it. Oracle doesn't find oci.dll file in 64-bit.

Therefore, you can try to change oracle home on the top. As a result of that, home path will change.